# Sum of 2 selects statement in sql with different where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the sum of 2 columns in one table but with different where the condition, the only difference is the amount per department is calculated based on 17% Margin. 
The Result should be the total revenue grouped by Event Name and Event ID.

for a sql Report, I have written 2 sql statements with different conditions and got the correct value for 2 columns but separately, i have summed both in a way but it was for one event.

```
SELECT EVT_ID, Event_Desc, Sum(Order_Total) as Total + (Select SUm(Order_Total *0.17) as Total from Orders Join Events EM On OrD.EVT_ID = EV.EVENTS_ID 
where EVT_START_DATE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' Order_Department = 'FAB'  )
From Orders Join Events EM On OrD.EVT_ID = EV.EVENTS_ID 
where EVT_START_DATE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' Order_Department <> 'FAB'  
Group by EVT_ID, Event_Desc
```

Comment: Could you perhaps add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: `, Sum(Order_Total) as Total + (Select SUm(Order_Total *0.17) as Total` this part in your SQL query does not looks ok.. Also you should keep in mind in SQL Server the `+` operator can also do string concatenation but i assume that that is not the problem here because `SUM()` should give back a decimal type

Answer (score 1):

```
select EVT_ID, Event_Desc, sum(Total)as Total 
from 
(
SELECT EVT_ID, Event_Desc, Sum(Order_Total) as Total 
 From Orders 
 Join Events EM On OrD.EVT_ID = EV.EVENTS_ID 
 where EVT_START_DATE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' and Order_Department <> 'FAB'
Group by EVT_ID, Event_Desc 
 union
Select EVT_ID, Event_Desc, SUm(Order_Total *0.17) as Total 
from Orders 
Join Events EM On OrD.EVT_ID = EV.EVENTS_ID 
 where EVT_START_DATE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31' and Order_Department = 'FAB' )  tbl   
 Group by EVT_ID, Event_Desc
```

> OR

```
 SELECT EVT_ID, Event_Desc, Sum(case when Order_Department = 'FAB' then Order_Total else Order_Total *0.17 end ) as Total 
 From Orders 
 Join Events EM On OrD.EVT_ID = EV.EVENTS_ID 
 where EVT_START_DATE between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'  
Group by EVT_ID, Event_Desc
```

Comment: welcome! If my answer properly responded to your question, please accept it by clicking the green check sign... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you could approach this with *conditional aggregation*. You  can use a `CASE` construct within the `SUM` aggregate function to check to which departement the current record belongs to and do the computation accordingly.

```
SELECT
    o.evt_id,
    event_desc,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN order_department = 'FAB' THEN order_total * 0.17 
        ELSE order_total END
    ) AS Total
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN events e On o.evt_id = e.events_id    
WHERE evt_start_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY 
    o.evt_id,
    event_desc
```

NB: most columns in your query are not prefixed with a table alias, making it unclear from which table they come from. I added them when it was possible to make an educated guess from your sql code, and I would higly recommend that you add prefixes to all of the remaining.